# Fastapi response - backslash

Tags: python, fastapi

I have variable holds time format of sql,
and need to return it,but it being esacped with backslash
while i print it back it doesn't

see  example:

```py
@app.get("/")

def test_string():
    sql_date ='YYYY-MM-DD"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'
    print(sql_date)
#get YYYY-MM-DD"HH24:MI:SS"Z"
    return sql_date
#return "YYYY-MM-DD\"HH24:MI:SS\"Z\""
```

How can i get the return from fastapi without the escaping backslash?

Comment: Usually the backslash is because of it being escaped in the output format; when you read the response in your client it will be converted to its original form. If you return a plain text response it should not be visible. https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#plaintextresponse

Answer (score 5):

Use a different response class instead of JSONResponse. For your case, the raw Response class may be enough.

For example:

```py
from fastapi import Response
@app.get("/")
def test_string():
    return Response(content = 'YYYY-MM-DD"HH24:MI:SS"Z"')
```

Or

```py
from fastapi import Response
@app.get("/", response_class = Response)
def test_string():
    return 'YYYY-MM-DD"HH24:MI:SS"Z"'
```

Comment: Thanks , is there a an option return this field as Json? I'd like to have more informative respond

Comment: @AviC You had got a response with scaping because the default response class was a JSONResponse. `"YYYY-MM-DD\"HH24:MI:SS\"Z\""` is itself a valid json response and you can load it using any json library. What are you trying to do?

Comment: This endpoint need to return a json response contain different informative fields, one of them should include a sql statement which has that time format